# category id with if:else statement

Tags: categories, ifelse

Basically im looking to show alternate images depending on the category id. Below I have shown my code, which doesnt work, but I would appreciate any information that any one could give me please! Some additional info about the categories can be seen in the screen shot. Also I have the channel:categories inside a channel:entries loop, the channel is grouped with the category. [image]

--

{exp:channel:categories style="linear"}

```
                                        {if cat_id =="70"}
                                        <figure>

                                                <a href="#">
                                                {if logo}

                                                    <img src="{logo}" class="logo" alt="{title}" />
                                                    {/if}
                                                </a>
                                            </figure>

                                        {if:else}

                                        //do something else

                                    {/exp:channel:categories}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you will need to do.

```
                                   {exp:channel:categories style="linear"}

                                        {if "{category_id}" == "70"}
                                            <figure>
                                                <a href="#">
                                                {if logo}
                                                    <img src="{logo}" class="logo" alt="{title}" />
                                                /if}
                                                </a>
                                            </figure>
                                        {if:else}

                                        //do something else

                                        {/if}

                                    {/exp:channel:categories}
```

Comment: nah dude, didnt work this time. I added a new image into the original comment to show u that its display the if:else each, even though the items have the cat_id of 70. The group id is "1" if that helps. Thanks for the help pal anyways, was appreciated as always :)

Comment: thanks for your help! `{exp:channel:categories style="linear"} {if "{category_id}" != "70"}` - this code worked to resolve the issue cheers dude!